# How to pass variables from bash script to AppleScript

Tags: terminal, applescript, bash

I have a file with a list of URL's. I need to pass each URL from a bash script to be used in an AppleScript.

```
while read urls
do 
    osascript -e \
    'tell application "Safari"
        tell window 1 
            tell current tab to open location "$urls"
        end tell
    end tell'
done <file.txt
```

This doesn't work. It passes the literal string `$urls` as the location to be opened in Safari. How can I pass the bash variable `$urls` to AppleScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
while read urls
do 
    osascript -e "tell application \"Safari\" to open location \"$urls\""
done<file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

The  quotes don't expand the variable in AppleScript.  What you need to do is  ESCAPE the quotes:

'tell current tab to open location \"$urls\"`

However, a better way to do this is using `run argv`.  For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
url="foobar.com"
osascript -e 'on run {myurl}' -e 'tell application "Safari" to set the URL of the document to myurl' -e 'end run' $url
```

My preference is to use a *separate* script for the AppleScript. In bash, this would look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
osascript -e 'do scriptname \"$url\"'
```

Comment: The double quotes *do* expand, the single ones around the whole script don't.

Comment: @patrix - I've never run into the issue where what was in the single quote didn't work as expected - at least from what I recall.

Comment: I'm getting an error - `syntax error: A “,” can’t go after this command name.`

Comment: That comma was a typo; it shouldn't be there.

Comment: Ok I see that now. Will this work to open a list of multiple url's?

Comment: @allan try `echo '$PATH'`

Comment: Thanks @patrix - I'm doing this all from memory on a Win10 machine.  :-)

Comment: Yes.  You can have as many arguments as you like.  It would take on the syntax:  `osascript -e script arg1 arg2 ... argN`.  You will just have to create the logic to handle the multiple arguments.